# How to determine the type of file system on an SD Card

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How to determine the type of file system on an SD Card (this card is not yet mounted. I need to determine the file system type so that i can mount the SDCard through a program according to the file system type)
Or from the terminal. For example "mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc1 /mnt"

Answer (score 7):

You might do a `file -s /dev/sdc1` and it could recognize the filesystem data.

And you might do `mount -t auto /dev/sdc1 /mnt` to have mount recognize it.

Comment: for a fat32 sd card it looks like it doesn't even mention fat32